# dijit.TitlePane: Expand/Collapse All. How to set an attribute on elements with a given classname

Tags: dojo

I have multiple title panes:

```
<div class="classname" data-dojo-props="title: 'Title Here', open: false" data-dojo-type="dijit.TitlePane">..</div>
```

Right now I have written this

```
<a onclick="dojo.forEach(dijit.registry.toArray(), function(item){  if (item.get('declaredClass')=='dijit.TitlePane'){item.set('open',true)};});">Expand All </a>
<a onclick="dojo.forEach(dijit.registry.toArray(), function(item){  if (item.get('declaredClass')=='dijit.TitlePane'){item.set('open',false)};});">Collapse All</a>
```

this successfully opens and closes all the title panes, but there is another title pane used in the page that I don't want affected by this. I tried using dojo.query('.classname').attr('open',false); but that didn't work.

I'm not experienced with dojo/dijits, how can I set open to true or false based on a class attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the widget to do this not the dom object,
 and that is what query is giving you the dom object.

```
dojo.query('.classname').forEach(function(node){
     dijit.getEnclosingWidget(node).set('open',false); 

})
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Also an FYI for anyone else because I didn't know.  In order for the class query to work I had to write `data-dojo-props="class:'classname'"`